# Does django-cms really integrate with django and models

Tags: django, django-models, content-management-system, django-cms

I am migrating an existing small business admin system that uses a variety of spreadsheets and access databases to a Linux server to provide both intranet and internet access to our own office staff, to external partners and to customers.

There is some fairly complex database work which will be using postgreSQL and python.

There needs to be a professional looking public website which can access some of the database content both to generic "customers" and tailored data visibility to actual clients.

None of the traditional CMS offerings like wordpress, drupal, joomla etc seemed flexible enough, so I found my way to django.

I've built models, populated data tables, built some basic views to manipulate the data and started to play a bit with html layout tags and css, and I've started looking at forms including crispy-forms.

I need to work with pdf files - scanning, uploading, splitting into single pages, displaying on the site alongside form data entry etc.

I was hoping that I could use django-cms to handle the aspects of the public facing words and pictures and dealing with the jpgs pdfs etc, and to do the page layout stuff, while using django models and python to simplify the database access and provide the intelligence.

When I read the django-cms docs around integrating models I get the impression that there is not really a proper integration - that you can build a site that switches between cms pages and django pages or maybe embeds a django view into a cms page, but I'm not sure if I can do the look and feel and static bits in cms and the dynamic bits on the same page in django without still having to do the work in django as well.

the django system revolves around the models, the django-cms docs read as if models are some sort of extra bit you might want to use.

There's talk of the different ways to integrate django models but they all treat the django model as a foreign item that can be added.

I've found other people who've asked "how does django-cms work with django models" and the answers seem to be no different from those that ask "how do I ad a django model to a drupal site"

So my question really is - does django-cms integrate with django to provide ease of building sites with good integration between cms features and model features or are they really two separate systems that can share space on the same page with a bit of work but don't play nice together in any useful way?

Is there another tool I can use for my static stuff and page formatting and navigation to integrate with my models and python code?

Comment: Last time I used django-cms I had to create custom plugins to get things done: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html - that seems to be the way to go if you want to include new things on your pages.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to pull in the django-cms structure and work within it early in the project or can I work with my django forms and get them right first then merge into the cms structure later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

Yes, it does integrate with django and it does provide ease of building sites with good integration between cms features and model features. Like comment by Simeon Visser hinted - you can create your own plugins to add managing different features into django cms part. And  most often - most things will not need such integration - simple django admin views and models will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's quite hard to get a mental handle on which parts of the overall design problem are fulfilled by different tools, especially having only dabbled with html and css in raw form. ATM I'm thinking crispy-forms plus Bootstrap3 to get my forms laid out and with pretty formatting, and then merging with django-cms to support all the text, photos, PDFs etc. I'm assuming I can then bring in the appropriate CSS stuff from a nice custom web template to give a style I like to the site as a whole.

Comment: I'm always using bootstrap and i have used it with both wordpress and django-cms. And it works just nice. Django-cms in itself does not hinder your progress much as long as you remember, its made for managing content. That means - you use it for publishing and changing the content you want to show the outside world. If some of that content comes from your backend databases, then yeah - you need to create some plugins for it. If you just want to show that stuff in your admin backend then it has nothing to do with django-cms and everything to do with django itself.

Comment: Only issue that i have had with django and bootstrap (don't remeber which version) was that all form fields required some class to look pretty (form-something...), so i had to create mixin for form class that would add this css class to all fields...

Comment: I ran aground with versions trying to add django-cms because I wasn't using the right versions for django-cms. I've used django 1.6 which may or may not be causing problems but there were issues with missing database keys, and the wrong version of reversion.

Comment: I think I'm going to carry on with my models for now as I need to get some stuff working to support urgent business. The I'll come back later and create a virtualenv tailored for django-cms and add the models, back in bit by bit.